# I was using Flutter's url_launcher package. However, the link is opening in the app itself. I want it to open in my browser

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using Flutter's url_launcher package. However, the link is opening in the app itself. I want it to open in my browser. Here is my code:

```
Future<void> launchUrlInBrowser(String url) async {
  Uri urlparsed=Uri.parse(url);
  if (!await launchUrl(urlparsed)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found for the problem is adding an additional parameter to launcUrl( ) method. The parameter is `mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication`. This parameter will launch the URL in an external app.

Here is my code fix:

```
Future<void> launchUrlInBrowser(String url) async {
  Uri urlparsed=Uri.parse(url);
  if (!await launchUrl(urlparsed,mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
  }
}
```

EDIT: Flutter now allows you to choose to open the URL in the same tab or a different tab. All you have to do is add an optional string after the mode parameter.

The strings can be one of the following:

- "_blank" opens the new URL in a new tab.
- "_self" opens the new URL in
  the current tab. Default behaviour when unset is to open the url in a
  new tab.

For example, `launchUrl(urlparsed,mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication),"_self")`